# Triangle with content showing through

Tags: css, html

Hi i'm trying to create a cross browser css triangle mask that also works in ie10.

heres what i have http://codepen.io/adamjw3/pen/RoxrNJ  but it doesn't work in ie. 
Any other way of doing this?

```
 .slider {
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 68% 81%, 100% 0);
        clip-path: polygon(0 0, 68% 81%, 100% 0);
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 30%;
      }

  img {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Its is not supported in IE. You can think of a different approach. Why don't you make a triangle via css and keep image inside it ?

More info here

http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path

**UPDATE: Another concept for triangle**

```css
.box1 {
  width: 232px;
  height: 180px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.box2 {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: rotate(45deg) skew(10deg, 10deg);
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 81px 0 0 16px;
}
.box2_bg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  top: -50%;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: -1;
  background: url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/brad_frost/128.jpg);
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: center top;
  transform: skew(-10deg, -10deg) rotate(-45deg);
  transition: .3s;
  background-size: 50%;
}
.box2_bg:hover {
  background-size: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
  <div class="box2">
    <div class="box2_bg"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can play with this.

Comment: yeah, any other way of doing a similar thing that would work in ie? do you mean using borders? can you show me code example with an image inside?

Comment: Yes like borders.

Comment: could you show me an example where i can get an image in the middle?

Comment: Play with the width and height along with media queries

Comment: ok. can this be done with an image tag instead of a background image

Comment: Yes there might be other ways,  but might be complex.  Just add inline css for the background image